# Transform image to byte array without compression in Java

Tags: java, image, encryption, bufferedimage

I would like to send an encrypted image over UDP, for that reason I would like to encrypt the image without compression using RC4. The reason I don't want compression is because I don't want the errors to multiply.
I am looking for a way to transform the image from BufferedImage to byte array without compression.

Comment: @HarryHarrison Can you give me a little bit more information about DataBufferByte since the oracle docs are not enough? For bufferedimages ill it store in an array the bytes for RGB for every pixels?

Comment: How is DataBufferByte even related to this question? You need to explain further and improve the quality of your question

Comment: @HarryHarrison DataBufferByte is used in the question you linked in the comments above

Comment: Sorry, didn't spot that in the other question as it's part of the attempt presented in the question which would be replaced by the code in the answer.

Comment: I would say you have two questions here

Comment: @HarryHarrison The proposed answer `ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);` compresses to jpg I think, so I do not want to use it.

Comment: @DanielAlder You were right my question was confusing, I edited it now.

Comment: @user5588938 - "jpg" is not the only possible value for that parameter